# $_POST stops at the first space it sees

Tags: php, mysql

I Have this code in **PHP** that generates the values in a Drop Down Box that is stored in a Database.

```
<select name=getdate>
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbjobsheetsf");
        $sql1 = "SELECT colDate FROM tbljs ";
        $queryR = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);    
        $p = 0;
                    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($queryR)) {   
                            echo "<option value=".$r['colDate'].">".$r['colDate']."</option>"; 
                    }

            mysqli_close($con); 

</select>
```

Example, the current value is **Thursday, August 28, 2014**. The problem is when i execute the code;

```
echo $_POST['getdate'];
```

the only value that is echoed is **Thursday,**

For Short, **It stops at the first space it sees**. What should I do?

The date is generated by JAVASCRIPT so it'll be hard for me to change those spaces to underlines, so I must retain the spaces.

Miss **Jenz**'s code helped me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to enclose the value of `options` inside quotes like

```
echo "<option value='".$r['colDate']."'>".$r['colDate']."</option>"; 
                    ^                 ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed some '' in the option value section. Try this code

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbjobsheetsf");
    $sql1 = "SELECT colDate FROM tbljs ";
    $queryR = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);    
    $p = 0;
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($queryR)) {   
        echo '<option value="'.$r['colDate'].'">'.$r['colDate'].'</option>'; 
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select name=getdate>
<?php
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbjobsheetsf");
            $sql1 = "SELECT colDate FROM tbljs ";
            $queryR = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);    
            $p = 0;
                        while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($queryR)) {   
                                echo "<option value='".$r['colDate']."'>".$r['colDate']."</option>";
                        }

                mysqli_close($con); 
    ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cdate = $_POST['getdate'];
$dates = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($cdate) );

echo $dates
```

you have to use date function to convert it into standard format

Answer (score 0):

If you try to print out the array $r and you see the whole date, serialize the value or store it in a text variable and then pass it to PHP. This should work.

If you print out the array and you don't get the whole date, recheck your query.

Why don't you try to put your date in a string variable and pass this through POST?